# Strings used in query always sent with NVARCHAR syntax, even if the underlying column is not unicode

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I'm noticing some odd behavior in the SQL generated for queries against string fields in MS SQL.

Server version: SQL Server 2014 12.0.5000.0

Collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Python version: 3.7

Our database has a mix of `NVARCHAR` (mostly newer) and `VARCHAR` (mostly older) fields. We are using SQLAlchemy to connect our Python application to the database, and even though we specify that a column is of type `String` (as opposed to `Unicode`), the executed SQL always comes out in `NVARCHAR` syntax (for example, `N'foo'`).

This ends up creating some obvious problems, as a simple index lookup on a multi-million row table turns into a giant string re-encoding operation.

The workaround I discovered is to pass in bytestrings (a la `s.encode("utf-8")`) instead of `str`s, but this is incredibly error-prone and hackish. I expected SQLAlchemy to handle this automatically since I told it that I'm querying against a `String` column and not a `Unicode` column.

If this is supposed to happen automatically, then maybe it's because it doesn't know the database collation? If so, how would I go about setting this?

Finally, as another point of reference, we're using pymssql. I am aware, through previous experience before we were using SQLAlchemy, that pymssql does the same thing (it assumes unicode strings are `NVARCHAR` while bytestrings are not). [Code here](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/891b20e29e4e247c17b202e8e34e5c739b6090ef/src/_mssql.pyx#L1779). As far as I can tell, SQLAlchemy just passes this off down the line. This behavior is a bit surprising to me since SQLAlchemy knows the column types and the type of connection/driver it's working with.

I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty, so if anyone happens to know where this could be reasonably patched, I'd be happy to contribute. My current investigation seems to indicate something to do with dialects and/or query/statement compilation.

I've uploaded a minimal example project to [GitHub](https://github.com/ianthetechie/pymssql_sqlalchemy_55098426).

**EDIT 2019-03-18**: Updated with new information based on investigation.

**EDIT 2019-03-23**: Added GitHub repo with minimal example.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Specifically, are you talking about using the ORM features of SQLAlchemy, or creating queries using SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language, or something else?

Comment: Sure thing @GordThompson. I have added an example on GitHub (link in updated question), along with some notes as to how you can verify this (either by looking at SQL Server query history or by the order of magnitude runtime difference in a 1.7mil row table).

Comment: @ianthetechie  Did you find a solution for this? I face this issue with py3.10, SQLAlchemy, pyodbc and MSSQL 2019 on VARCHAR fields as well. All params are cast as NVARCHAR and are leading to delayed query results.

Comment: @VarunVerma I posted a workaround in the original post: pass in bytestrings, for example by passing `s.encode("utf-8")` rather than `s` itself. I have since moved on from the company using this architecture so I cannot comment on whether this still works in 2023 or if a better solution is available.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue. Your MCVE was very helpful.

It was interesting to see that, for your ORM example, SQL Profiler showed no evidence that SQLAlchemy was retrieving the column metadata before running the SELECT query against the table. Apparently it believes that it knows enough about the columns to construct a working query, even though (as it turns out) it is not necessarily the most efficient one.

I knew that SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language would retrieve the table metadata, so I tried a similar SELECT using

```python
metadata = MetaData()
my_table = Table('test', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = select([my_table.c.id, my_table.c.key])\
    .select_from(my_table)\
    .where(my_table.c.key == value)
cnxn = engine.connect()
items = cnxn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

and although SQLAlchemy did indeed retrieve the metadata using

```sql
SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[table_schema],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[table_name],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[column_name],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[is_nullable],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[data_type],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[ordinal_position],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[character_maximum_length],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[numeric_precision],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[numeric_scale],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[column_default],
       [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[collation_name]
FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns]
WHERE  [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[table_name] = Cast(
       N'test' AS NVARCHAR(max))
       AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[table_schema] = Cast(
           N'dbo' AS NVARCHAR(max))
ORDER  BY [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[columns].[ordinal_position]
```

a portion of whose output is

```
TABLE_SCHEMA  TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  IS_NULLABLE  DATA_TYPE  ORDINAL_POSITION  CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
------------  ----------  -----------  -----------  ---------  ----------------  ------------------------
dbo           test        id           NO           int        1                 NULL
dbo           test        key          NO           varchar    2                 50
```

the resulting SELECT query still used an `nvarchar` literal

```sql
SELECT test.id, test.[key] 
FROM test 
WHERE test.[key] = N'record123456'
```

Finally, I did the same tests using `pyodbc` instead of `pymssql` and the results were essentially the same. I was curious if SQLAlchemy's dialect for pyodbc might take advantage of [setinputsizes](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) to specify the parameter types (i.e., `pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR` instead of `pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR`), but apparently it does not.

So, I'd say that for the time being your best bet is to continue encoding your string values into bytes that correspond to the character set of the `varchar` column you are querying (not utf-8). Of course, you can also dive into source code for the SQLAlchemy dialect(s) and submit a PR to make SQLAlchemy better.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, and for testing `pyodbc` as well. That actually surprised me just a little bit, but at the same time, it's not entirely unreasonable for the underlying driver to assume that the parameters passed are of the correct type. I am very much interested in contributing a PR to fix this, but I hit a wall with my current approach. I realize it may not be pymssql specific, but have a look at the code I just pushed to my MCVE repo with a (buggy) dialect-specific column implementation.

Comment: My question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936620/why-does-my-query-break-when-it-is-parameterized.is similar to this right?  So, there is no way of specifying `charset` or `collation` etc. to make it work?! Converting to `bytes` everywhere is really painful.